# Is it possible to miss a connection?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm writing a simple asynchronous tcp server & client program and I am curious if it's possible that the method "waitForConnections" misses a connection because it's still busy with accepting the new connection or start listening to it.

I tested it with 250 clients and I didn't notice a connection loss.

**The code i used for testing:**

```
  for(int counter = 0; 250 > counter; counter++)
        {
            final int localCounter = counter;

            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    Socket socket = new Socket(ip, port);

                    System.out.println("Connected!");

                    DataOutputStream out =
                            new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                    out.writeUTF("#" + localCounter + " hello server!");

                    listenToConnection(socket);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }).start();
        }
```

**The server code:**

```
public class Server extends Thread {

private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private final Integer port;
private int amountConnections = 0;

public Server(Integer port) {
    this.port = port;
}

public void run() {
    startServer(port);
}

private void startServer(Integer port) {
    System.out.println("Server started!");
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        waitForConnections();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void waitForConnections() {
    try {
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("New connection from: " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress()  + " - amount connections: " + amountConnections);
        amountConnections++;
        asyncListenToConnection(socket);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        waitForConnections();
    }
}

// Creates a new thread for each connection to listen to
private void asyncListenToConnection(Socket socket) {
    new Thread(() -> {
        while (!socket.isClosed()) {
            try {
                DataInputStream in =
                        new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

                System.out.println("Connection: " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress() + " says: " + in.readUTF());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                closeConnection(socket);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

private void closeConnection(Socket socket) {
    if (!socket.isClosed() || socket.isConnected()) {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Connection: " + socket.getRemoteSocketAddress() + " has left");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm new to Java, threading and sockets so any tips are welcome including improving the code.

Comment: You can "miss" a connection in this fashion only if your network buffer got overflown while you were answering previous requests. This is typically known as DoS. Also, not sure this is on topic here, looks more like SO material to me.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. I thought stackoverflow was more ment for problems, this isn't a really problem, just a question. That's why i posted it here. @Mods, if this isn't the right section, could you maybe move it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `waitForConnections` can die of stack overflow because you keep calling it recursively. With enough short-lived connections you'll exceed the stack depth. Since Java does not support tail-call elimination, I'd write an explicit loop.

Comment: It's also possible that the OS may actively reject connections (looking at you Windows). You could also have a look at [`ServerSocket(port, backlog, bindAddr)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket(int,%20int,%20java.net.InetAddress)), look at the `backlog` parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you call

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
```

with no backlog parameter, according to the Oracle Documentation for ServerSocket at:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket%28int%29

> The maximum queue length for incoming connection indications (a
>   request to connect) is set to 50. If a connection indication arrives
>   when the queue is full, the connection is refused.

You can reduce the chances of this by increasing the backlog. If you also write the client code, you can have clients automatically retry after a connection refused.